# Why does Twitter Bootstrap's map file refer to itself in the sources?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, source-maps

In bootstrap.css.map, I noticed that the sources contained

```
{"version":3,"sources":["bootstrap.css","less/normalize.less","less/print.less","less/glyphicons.less","less/scaffolding.less","less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less","less/mixins/tab-focus.less","less/mixins/image.less","less/type.less","less/mixins/text-emphasis.less","less/mixins/background-variant.less","less/mixins/text-overflow.less","less/code.less","less/grid.less","less/mixins/grid.less","less/mixins/grid-framework.less","less/tables.less","less/mixins/table-row.less","less/forms.less","less/mixins/forms.less","less/buttons.less","less/mixins/buttons.less","less/mixins/opacity.less","less/component-animations.less","less/dropdowns.less","less/mixins/nav-divider.less","less/mixins/reset-filter.less","less/button-groups.less","less/mixins/border-radius.less","less/input-groups.less","less/navs.less","less/navbar.less","less/mixins/nav-vertical-align.less","less/utilities.less","less/breadcrumbs.less","less/pagination.less","less/mixins/pagination.less","less/pager.less","less/labels.less","less/mixins/labels.less","less/badges.less","less/jumbotron.less","less/thumbnails.less","less/alerts.less","less/mixins/alerts.less","less/progress-bars.less","less/mixins/gradients.less","less/mixins/progress-bar.less","less/media.less","less/list-group.less","less/mixins/list-group.less","less/panels.less","less/mixins/panels.less","less/responsive-embed.less","less/wells.less","less/close.less","less/modals.less","less/tooltip.less","less/popovers.less","less/carousel.less","less/mixins/clearfix.less","less/mixins/center-block.less","less/mixins/hide-text.less","less/responsive-utilities.less","less/mixins/responsive-visibility.less"]
```

Why does it reference to itself?

Comment: It's not referring to itself. The map file is referring to the css file it is based on. *.css != *.css.map

Comment: Sorry my question is poorly phrased. If you look at jquery, `jquery.min.js.map` will have `jquery-2.1.3.js` as its source. So following that logic, shouldn't `bootstrap.css` instead be `bootstrap.less`, the real source?

Comment: That depends on your debugger. jqery.min.js and jquery-2.1.3.js are written in the same language, which means that the same parser will understand them. bootstrap.css and bootstrap.less are not. A straight css parser won't understand the less code and won't be able to connect the map and the source.

Answer (score 0):

`sources` is referencing the files that this sourcemap had as original sources. I.e., this source map does not map from minified css back to less, it maps from minified css back to css, presumably after less compilation.

This might be useful if you are trying to take advantage of browser support for sourcemaps, as the browser will present the css files as the original sources and, as ericm301 says, it need only be able to handle css to do this, not less.